# C# regex with a certain word and hashtags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm still learning how to write a regex, but this I can't solve on my own.

have a string that contains a word looking like this : ##companyname##

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\b##companyname##\b", setup.Company, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: What is the string you're trying to match against, exactly?

Comment: Seems like the `#` characters are screwing up the `\b` functionality.

Comment: I'm giving it the following `<p style="text-align: center;">
    ##companyName##
</p>`

Comment: I don't think you need the boundary "\b" the "##companyname##" pattern should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\b matches a word boundary, so it won't match # character.
Use \B instead to match a non-word boundary.

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\B##companyname##\B", setup.Company, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: A word boundary will never match a character. It matches the position between a word character and a non word character (or the other way round). `A\b#` would be true

Answer (score 0):

That is because word boundary matches a word boundary position such as whitespace or the beginning or end of the string.

But your regex itself contains `#`. Do this:

```
"##companyname##"
```

The original regex was not a word boundary.

Comment: There is no need to write `#\bc`, this is always true, so you can just remove the word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the meaning of the `\b` specifier:

> Specifies that the match must occur on a boundary between \w (alphanumeric) and \W (nonalphanumeric) characters. The match must occur on word boundaries — that is, at the first or last characters in words separated by any nonalphanumeric characters.

In your case it is not real boundary between *words* because in your case both `#` and `<` and `>` are not word characters.

In my oppinion just replacing simply `##companyname##` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between \b and \B in regex**

`\b` matches the empty string at the *beginning or end of a word*.  `\B` matches the empty string not at the beginning or end of a word.

```
content = Regex.Replace(content,
                        @"\B##companyname##\B",
                        setup.Company,
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                       );
```

You can test this regex `B##companyname##\B` here - http://regexr.com/38p8i

[image]

P.S: Started learning regex today :)